# Regular Expression with 2 Decimal Places or Whole numbers and a Range

Tags: regex

I want to validate pH Levels in my input with a digit and with only one or two decimal places, or just with a digit.

My regex expression contains some errors in it (input can reach 100):

```
/^([0-9]|1[0-4])+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/
```

pH ranges only from 1.00 to 14.00.
values in the range (1-14) with .0 or .00 (e.g. 3.00 and 4.0) are also considered valid

Valid values

> 1, 1.0, 1.00, 2.3, 2.12, 2.54, 13.22, 13.99

Invalid values

> 0, 0.99, 14.01, 1.123

Comment: In what programming language are you going to use it?

Comment: @Alfabravo both PHP and Javascript

Comment: Why not asking about string length and something that parses the number and just ask if < 14?

Comment: @chris85 I was required to do it via regex only

Comment: @DanielKrom I was required to do it via regex only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(([1-9]|1[0-3])(\.\d\d?)?|14(\.00?)?)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/B9eKXN/1

In particular, look at the unit tests which all seem to be passing.

Comment: Enclose the whole regex in a (non-capture) group. The `^` anchor acts only on the left part of regex whilst `$` on the right part only.

Comment: @Toto how exactly would you do that?

Comment: OK - I think this is working... Wow, my first attempt was not right :)

Answer (score 0):

That expression was  testing from 0.00 until 16.00 and it worked good, be carefull to that take exactly two point decimal or it will not match

```
^(([1-9]|1[0-3])\.\d\d)|(14\.00)$
```